# Calculate application hit count day wise in java

Tags: session, hitcounter

I have a requirement where in i have to calculate the number of hit count for the application day wise and generate a report for it. What i have been told is to create a table and then keep on updating the count whenever user accesses the application. Can anyone guide me how to proceed. Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you give us a hint what kind of "App" we are talking about?

Comment: I am relating to a web application. Whenever i will login to my application, there should be a count generated which shall get stored in database. And must be calculated on day wise.

Comment: If it's a web-app, you can use googleAnalytics, for example. It also deals with the problem of distinguishing between visitors, visits, impressions, and that stuff. you only have to decide what page you want to track.

Comment: Andreas but is there any reference to how to implement google analytics in web application?

Comment: Sure. You only need an account, the rest is well explained: http://www.google.com/analytics/